# Transform XML with properties in columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @hDoc XML = 
'<orders>
    <mail>
        <set id="s" sequence="1" version="1.1" >
            <set id="order" sequence="4" version="">
                <property id="id" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[&#8364; 10000]]></property>
                <set id="article" sequence="1" version="">
                    <property id="basepricevalue" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[155.66]]></property>
                    <property id="quantity" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[3]]></property>
                    <property id="senior" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[16]]></property>                    
                    <property id="vat" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[21]]></property>                    
                </set>
                <set id="article" sequence="2" version="">
                    <property id="basepricevalue" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[465.99]]></property>
                    <property id="quantity" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[12]]></property>
                    <property id="senior" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[17]]></property>   
                    <property id="vat" label="" sequence="0" resource_label="" show_type="" name="" ><![CDATA[18]]></property>                                      
                </set>
            </set>
        </set>
    </mail>
</orders>';
```

Desired output:

```
OrderID    basepricevalue     quantity     senior     vat
10000      155.66             3            16         21
10000      465.99             12           17         18
```

This is what I have at the moment but performance is really bad because of all the cross apply's.  I'm certain there must be better way to do this.

```
SELECT 
  orderid   = nd.x.value('(property/text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)'),
  price = ndprice.x.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
  quantity = ndquantity.x.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
  senior = ndsenior.x.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
  vat = ndvat.x.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')

FROM (VALUES (@hDoc)) hdoc(orders)
CROSS APPLY orders.nodes('orders/mail//set[@id="order"]') nd(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('set[@id="article"]') nd2(x)
CROSS APPLY nd2.x.nodes('property[@id="basepricevalue"]') ndprice(x)
CROSS APPLY nd2.x.nodes('property[@id="quantity"]') ndquantity(x)
CROSS APPLY nd2.x.nodes('property[@id="senior"]') ndsenior(x)
CROSS APPLY nd2.x.nodes('property[@id="vat"]') ndvat(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of some of the CROSS APPLY's, since you can use query() to get certain elements

```
SELECT 
  orderid = O.orderset.query('property[@id="id"]/text()').value('.','varchar(max)'),
  price = A.article.query('property[@id="basepricevalue"]/text()').value('.','float'),
  quantity = A.article.query('property[@id="quantity"]/text()').value('.','int'),
  senior = A.article.query('property[@id="senior"]/text()').value('.','int'),
  vat = A.article.query('property[@id="vat"]/text()').value('.','int')
FROM (VALUES (@hDoc)) hdoc(orders)
CROSS APPLY orders.nodes('orders/mail//set[@id="order"]') O(orderset)
CROSS APPLY O.orderset.nodes('set[@id="article"]') A(article)
```

Or you could indeed use value() directly, using a more specific xpath.
And take it's first occurence [1].

Also, you can get rid of an extra CROSS APPLY by directly getting the nodes from the XML type.

```
SELECT 
  orderid = O.orderset.value('(property[@id="id"]/text())[1]','varchar(max)'),
  price = A.article.value('(property[@id="basepricevalue"]/text())[1]','float'),
  quantity = A.article.value('(property[@id="quantity"]/text())[1]','int'),
  senior = A.article.value('(property[@id="senior"]/text())[1]','int'),
  vat = A.article.value('(property[@id="vat"]/text())[1]','int')
FROM @hDoc.nodes('orders/mail//set[@id="order"]') O(orderset)
CROSS APPLY O.orderset.nodes('set[@id="article"]') A(article)
```